# PHP Array to JS array and restructure

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have two PHP strings that looks like this (obviously shortened for the question):

```
 $year [
    [0]=>2003
    [1]=>2003

    [2]=>2004
    [3]=>2004

    [4]=>2005
    [5]=>2005



]

 $cost [
    [0]=>200
    [1]=>300
    [2]=>400
    [3]=>500
    [4]=>410
    [5]=>510
]
```

I need to turn the PHP arrays above into a JAVASCRIPT array formatted exactly as below:

```
     var newData=[            
          ['2003', 200,300],
          ['2004', 400,500],
          ['2005', 410,510]       
        ];
```

When I type in the JS array implicitly (as above) all works fine (ie the graphics render correctly). However after several hours of trying different approaches, I cannot work out how to easily generate the newData array dynamically (ie from PHP arrays as shown) in exactly the JS Array format shown.

Comment: How do you know how much entries have the 2003 and which of them should take from $cost?

Comment: Take us back one step to how you created these arrays. More efficient to start there

Comment: @legomolina the two PHP arrays are produced in such a way that the key of each array always matches the key of the other. So whatever key value is for array ($year) it will match array($cost).  I will extend the question example to show you

Comment: @charliefl im afraid the php array formats are fixed. Major implications of changing those,

Comment: in PHP: `json_encode($array);` - in JS: `const array = JSON.parse(json);` - the restructuring / merging can be done in PHP or JS.

Comment: There are some things still unclear about the requirements. Will the values of year always be in order? (ie - will the years always be grouped together?) Is there a fixed or variable number of costs associated with each year?

Comment: @Prisoner yes always in order. So 2003 could have (say) 10 instances and that will create 10 cost instances. (The form handler user side forces that).

Comment: @le_m encoding the php array as a string I get. I am not getting the second part though. const array = JSON.parse(json); How does that apply?

Comment: @le_m You do not have to JSON.parse the json_encoded variable, because it will not be trasferred as a string, but as part of the page code and therefore as the corresponding type for the varaible. (In this case object or array)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer How do you know that OP returns the array within the HTML document? If OP does so, then you are right of course.

Comment: @le_m If he does return it via a special ressource, he should set the HTTP header Content-Type to application/json instead, wich will result in not needing the JSON.parse again,

Answer (score 1):

Your quest can be separated in two tasks: 
First of all you want to combine both arrays. I guess you want to do this based on the keys they have. There are multiple functions for that in PHP, like `array_combine` or `array_reduce`. 
Yet for your case the easiest way is a for_each loop, because you have duplicate values in the $year array.

```
$combined_array = [];
foreach ($year as $id => $year_val) {
    if (!array_key_exists($year_val, $combined_array)) {
        $combined_array[$year_val] = [(string)$year_val];
    }
    $combined_array[$year_val][] = $cost[$id];
}
```

Now you have the years as keys, what you do not want, so you can use `array_values` to remove the keys again.

```
$combined_array = array_values($combined_array);
```

The second task is quite easy: Go to the PHP file, that loads the script you want to provide the array to. Add this before you load the script:

```
<script>
    var myPhpArray = <?php echo json_encode($combined_array) ?>;
</script>
```

After that the PHP array is accessible from JS in the variable `myPhpArray.

Comment: Thank you. I think the bit of this i am not doing right is JSON.parse. I have the php array restructured ok. And i have used (js) var array = "<?php echo json_encode($combined_array)?>"; .....but that failed (althouigh i have used that method before without problems)?

Comment: Im sorry. I removed the JSON.parse part, because it is not neccessary. Valid JSON is automatically parsed as an JS varaible by the JS engine.

Comment: @WChris, DONT use the quotes between your php echo call. It will make your javascript interpret the code as a string and it must interpret it as javascript code that structures and array.

Answer (score 1):

if you respect the structure in the example, the following would do the job:

```
<?php

$year = [
   0 => 2003,
   1 => 2003,
   ...
];

$cost = [
   0 => 200,
   1 => 300,
   ...
];

for($i=0;$i<SIZE_OF_ARRAY;$i+=2)
     $newData[] = [(string) $year[$i], $cost[$i], $cost[$i+1]];

?>
```

Now in the javascript portion of the code you just need:

```
<script>
    var newData = <?= json_encode($newData); ?>
</script>
```

Note that i didnt use the quotes between the php code because i do want the javascript to parse the php output as javascript code and not as a javascript string.

Comment: @BigBlastThat helps with structuring the PHP data but the issue i am having the problem with is replicating it in JS exactly......json_encode(<?php echo $newData?>); fails

Comment: no no, you just need: `var newData = <?= json_encode($newData) ?>;` or, if you dont have `short_open_tags` enabled in your php.ini, `var newData = <?php echo json_encode($newData); ?>`

Comment: yeah that was what i tried before SO post. Its not happening though. Hmmm...at least Im not doing something really daft. And for that an upvote sir

Comment: ps my prior comment back to you without the json_encode was honestly just a copy paste typo (see my earlier comments to others who responded).

Comment: If the portion of the code that structures the data works correctly, i dont see any reason for the portion that displays the PHP array as a JS Array not work... do you have some other info about the error that you are receiving? Some weird output that being displayed?

Comment: @WChris i've updated my answer to clarify the structure of the code you must implement to achieve your goal.

Comment: @BigBlast WChris already mentioned in another comment, that there might be 10 costs for 2003 and only 2 for 2004, so your code does not work for his case. Good approach anyway

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. Your answers showed I was going about things the right way (json_encode etc). What has happened though is that the legacy system producing the PHP Arrays was not correcting the values for integers rather than strings. The recipient plug in needed INTs -- see the output array format in the question

So json_encoding the php array worked OK - but it was encoding string rather than INT data values. Fixed that and now it all seems fine.

PS If you look at the orginal question yyou will see the OP array in JS needed two datatypes. And of course it was only getting strings. Lesson there for sure!

Heres the snippet

```
             var a = ['1','2','3'];
             var result = a.map(function (x) { 
             return parseInt(x, 10);
```